# Update data of fragment without completly loading the same fragment again

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use this to load a fragment:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Fragment fragment = new Messaging();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        FriendInfo friend = null;
        friend = friendAdapter.getItem(position);
        args.putString(FriendInfo.USERNAME, friend.userName);
        args.putString(FriendInfo.PORT, friend.port);
        args.putString(FriendInfo.IP, friend.ip);

        setTitle(friend.userName);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        mTitle = getTitle();
        friendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }
```

As you can see this loads the same Fragment everytime, but I only need to have different values for `FriendInfo.USERNAME`, `FriendInfo.PORT` and `FriendInfo.IP`.
How to do this without loading the whole fragment again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a fragment is already attached to the Activity using FragmentManager's `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` methods. Try finding the fragment first -- if you do find it, just update it yourself; otherwise create it anew as you are already doing.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have expressed myself badly, but my actual problem is to update it by myself.

Comment: Well, it's your fragment, you can add any public methods you want that will do the trick. Just cast the Fragment you find from FragmentManager to the appropriate type and have at it.